# How do I treat a block of text as if it were a figure?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016, caption

I'm writing an article on software development, and frequently want to insert a block of code that look something like this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css", "~/Content/site.css"));
}
```

I want to always keep all the lines together, but I can manage that, but I also want to caption and cross reference it, so I can place 'Listing 1 - The Bundles`below it, and then insert references to`Listing 1` in other places in the document. Is this possible and if so, how could I do it?

Comment: You can e.g. insert your code into a one-cell table or into a text box (make it's alignment "in line with text"), hide the borders and you can add a caption to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert your code into a one-cell table or into a text box (make it's alignment "in line with text"). Then you can hide the borders and add a caption to it.